# Prove closure of a group $(G,*)$ where $G=\mathbb{R_0}\times\mathbb{R},(\mathbb{R_0}=\mathbb{R} \setminus\{0\}),(a,b)*(x,y)=(ax,a^2y+b)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to prove closure of the given group?

$\forall (a,b),(x,y)\in G\Rightarrow (a,b)*(x,y)\in G$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** (for the general exercise of proving this is a group)

Consider the set of matrices
$$
m(a,b)
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & 0\\
0 & a^{2} & b\\
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}_{0} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a,b), (x,y) \in G$

Now, we have to show that

$(a,b)*(x,y) = (ax, a^2y+b) \in G$

Since $a, x \in \mathbb{R}_0 \Rightarrow ax  \in \mathbb{R}_0$ because $a,x \neq 0 \Rightarrow ax \neq 0$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is closed under multiplication.

Since $a, b, y \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow a^2y+b \in \mathbb{R}$ because $\mathbb{R}$ is closed under addition and multiplication.

Thus, $(a,b)*(x,y) \in G$